# Use value of search into Url React Native

Tags: react-native, api, searchbar

I am kind of new in React-native, and I am trying to use a searchbar to find a city and use it as an input for a Url, but unfortunately it seems that is not triggered on time I guess due to the useEffect, could you help me please? From the url I want to get the latitude an longitude values of different cities to use it later in an API.
It works for cities of USA and Mexico

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';
import MaterialCommunityIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

export default App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [city_data, setCity_data] = useState([]);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
  const [resultSearch, setResultSearch] = useState('');

  const onChangeSearch = (query) => setSearchQuery(query);
  

  let place = `https://search.reservamos.mx/api/v2/places?q=${resultSearch}`;
  
  console.log(place);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(place)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        // city_data: [name of city, latitude, longitude]
        setCity_data([
          json['0'].city_name,
          json['0'].state,
          json['0'].lat,
          json['0'].long,
        ]);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  let latit = city_data[2];
  let longit = city_data[3];

  console.log(resultSearch)

  const search = () => {
    return (
      <Searchbar
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={onChangeSearch}
        value={searchQuery}
        icon={() => <MaterialCommunityIcon name="map-search" size={25} />}
        onSubmitEditing={() => setResultSearch(searchQuery)}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 0, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      ) : (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
          }}>
          <View>{search()}</View>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, color: 'green', textAlign: 'center' }}>
            The latitude of {city_data[0]}, {city_data[1]} is: {city_data[2]} {resultSearch}
          </Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You've given an empty array as the dependency list for your `useEffect`. This means that the `useEffect` will only call the fetch API **once** on mount.

What you want here is to call the fetch API when the search query changes. So adding `place` to the list will solve your problem.

```js
useEffect(() => {

   (...)

}, [place]); // dependency-list
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extra state for storing Search Query...

Also, your `fetch` was not being used correctly.

I've corrected it and it should work perfectly fine.

Let me know if you get any error in this.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { FlatList, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Searchbar } from "react-native-paper";
import MaterialCommunityIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";

export default App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [city_data, setCity_data] = useState([]);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");

  const GetSearchResults = async () => {
    try {
      let place = `https://search.reservamos.mx/api/v2/places?q=${searchQuery}`;
      await fetch(place)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
          // city_data: [name of city, latitude, longitude]
          setCity_data([
            json["0"].city_name,
            json["0"].state,
            json["0"].lat,
            json["0"].long,
          ]);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    } catch (error) {
      // log errors here if any
    }
  };

  const search = () => (
    <Searchbar
      placeholder="Search"
      onChangeText={(query) => setSearchQuery(query)}
      value={searchQuery}
      icon={() => <MaterialCommunityIcon name="map-search" size={25} />}
      onSubmitEditing={() => GetSearchResults()}
    />
  );

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 0, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      ) : (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: "column",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          <View>{search()}</View>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, color: "green", textAlign: "center" }}>
            The latitude of {city_data[0]}, {city_data[1]} is: {city_data[2]}
            {searchQuery}
          </Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```